# facing a problem of defineProps is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

I am facing a problem of "defineProps is not defined". I am not sure why is this not working where the code below actually works

```js
const props = defineProps({
  time:Number
})
```

App.vue

```html
<script setup>
import Bomb from './Bomb.vue'
</script>

<template>
   <Bomb :time="4" />
</template>
```

Bomb.vue

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['time'])
</script>

<template>
    <div>
    {{props.time}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It's a typo: `defneProps` != `defineProps`

Comment: has edited the defneProps typo to defineProps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Bomb.vue's snippet "defneProps" is a typo, it's also a known false-positive warning from eslint-plugin-vue.

https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#compiler-macros-such-as-defineprops-and-defineemits-generate-no-undef-warnings

The official solution is to install and use [vue-eslint-parser](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-eslint-parser)